# How do you run pytest or flask8 from powershell?

Tags: python, powershell, pytest, pipenv

I am trying to run a pipeline on python project. I am not able to run the pytest task nor the flask8.

I have the following scripts:

```
  - python -V
  - $env:Path += ";C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\Scripts"
  - pipenv shell
  - pipenv install --dev
  - pipenv graph
  - pipenv shell
```

giving the following output:

```
 $ python -V
 Python 3.7.6
 $ pipenv shell
 Launching subshell in virtual environment
 Windows PowerShell 
 Copyright (C) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
 PS C:\project> $ pipenv install --dev
 Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock (aac0cc)
 To activate this projects virtualenv, run pipenv shell.
 Alternatively, run a command inside the virtualenv with pipenv run.
 $ pipenv graph
 ----
 pytest==4.6.9
 ----
 - setuptools [required: Any, installed: 46.1.3]
 $ pipenv shell
 Launching subshell in virtual environment
 Windows PowerShell 
 Copyright (C) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
 $ set PYTHONPATH=./src:./
 $ py.test
 py.test : The term 'py.test' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or 
 operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path 
 is correct and try again.
 At C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Temp\build_script515891919\script.ps1:221 char:1
 + py.test
 + ~~~~~~~
     + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (py.test:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Uploading artifacts for failed job
00:00
 ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

Why can't I run the py.test? 
I have tried the following command as well
`python -m py.test`

Comment: python files have to have py extension. Did you mean to type test.py ? And also, make sure to have that file in your working directory

Comment: py.test is a testing tool

Comment: Don't use `pipenv shell` as you are not in an interactive shell. `pipenv run pytest ...` should do the trick.

Comment: thank you @hoefling, it works!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
$ pipenv run pytest ...
```

when you are not in an interactive shell (e.g. when invoking `pytest` on a CI server). This will run the command in `pipenv`'s virtual environment. The same applies to `poetry`:

```
$ poetry run pytest ...
```

invokes `pytest` in the virtual environment managed by `poetry`.